# How to fetch single elements from xml list using LINQ in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to fetch data from XML file and store the values to the C# variables List. So I can use it in different methods also.Below is my XML format:

```
<fieldmetadata>
<field>
    <name>Object Text</name>
    <datatype>Text</datatype>
    <label>ABC</label>
</field>

<field>
    <name>Object Short Text</name>
    <datatype>String</datatype>
    <label>PQR</label>
</field>
```

and below is my C# Code:

```
public List<string> getAllidentifiers()
{     
    List<string> listx = new List<string>();

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Path.GetTempPath() + "\\XMLFormat.xml");
    xdoc.Descendants("field").Select(p => new
    {
        name = p.Element("name").Value,
        datatype = p.Element("datatype").Value,
        label = p.Element("label").Value
    }).ToList().ForEach(p =>
    {
        listx.Add(p.name);
        listx.Add(p.datatype);
        listx.Add(p.label);
    });       

   return listx;
}
```

How can I fetch list elements to variables.

Comment: So what data do you want to retrieve? In what format? What have you tried?...

Comment: I want to fetch the xml list data into variables

Comment: It sounds like you should be creating a class to represent a field, with `Name`, `DataType` and `Label` properties - you could then create a `List<Field>`. Is that the sort of thing you're looking for? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: But I dont know how to set this values

Comment: Set which values? You're already retrieving the three values you want, so which part is confusing you? Do you know how to create your own class, and give it a constructor?

Answer (score 1):

As your current code just returns a flat list of strings you can achieve it like this:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml")
                      .Descendants("field")
                      .SelectMany(f => f.Elements().Select(e => e.Value))
                      .ToList();
```

But I think a better solution would be to return an `IEnumerablE<Field>`, create the type:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize the file like this:

- [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/364253/6400526)

Comment: I want to store that xml data into List<string> and then fetch there values in variables.

Comment: @Angad - the *fetch there values in variables* is not really clear. If you just want a flat string collection then the answer shows it. Otherwise if you want 3 lists, for for each field, then better go with the  `Field` class, deserialize the xml and then use linq `.Select` to just retrieve  the different properties.